# About the proof by induction of the base representation of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In Number Theory class, we were showed the Theorem:
"For a fixed $b>1$, for all $x>0$ there exists $n\geq0$ and unique $x_{0},x_{1}...,x_{n}\in\{0,1,...,b-1\}$ such that $x_n=0$ and $x=x_0+x_1\cdot b+...+x_n\cdot b^n$.

What I don't understand is the proof, which uses the method of induction. The existence part is as follows:

If $b>x>0$, then $n=0$ and $x=x_0$.

If $x>b$, integer division.
$x=b\cdot q+x_0$, $b>x_0\geq 0$.

Then, $x>q>0$. By induction hypothesis, there exist $x_{1}...,x_{n}\in\{0,1,...,b-1\}$ so that $q=x_1+x_2\cdot b+...+x_n\cdot b^{n-1}$. Substituting we get $x=x_0+x_1\cdot b+...+x_n\cdot b^n$, as we wanted.

The thing I can't quite grasp is the induction step. I've always seen inductive proofs as starting from the appropiate n, then supposing that it holds for $n$ and seeing it implies it holds for $n+1$. In this case, I see two cases (in the first, $n=0$), but I don't get the "by induction hypothesis" part here. So, the question is: what is the base case, and how exactly is the inductive step? What numbers (less than b, greater than x...?) is the hypothesis about?

Answer (score 1):

The base case is $0 \leq x < b$. The [implicit] assumption in the inductive step is that the representation is possible for $b^{k-1} \leq x < b^k$, and for $b^k \leq x < b^{k+1}$ they use the division algorithm. I think they would have to prove that the quotient really falls in the bounds for the induction hypothesis to make the proof rigorous, but that's easily done.

Inductive proofs often assume such things if they are very simple or are not the main focus of the content. If you're taking a Number Theory course at the beginner level however, I think this should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your Number Theory class should have discussed something called [complete induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction). The inductive hypothesis is that you have Base b representations for all numbers less than $x$.